# How to eliminate *chapter 0* in the **table of contents**

Tags: memoir, chapters

How to eliminate *chapter 0* in the **table of contents**

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}   
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead{\itshape\chaptername\thechapter}{}{\itshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}%
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}%
\pagestyle{mine}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.75cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\chapter{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should not have a chapter 0, so there is an error in your document in code you have not shown.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Move `\pagestyle{mine}` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Nothing has changed, it remains chapter 0 above

Comment: If I add `\end{document}` at the end of your MWE, I get a document that has no chapter 0.

Comment: You say memoir but use book.

Answer (score 1):

A command such as `\chapter*{Introduction}` produces an unnumbered chapter that does not appear in the table of contents.  If what should be Chapter 1 is showing up as Chapter 0 or Chapter 2, you should `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` before it.